# Formula that grabs numbers from another column if the cell in the current column is empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I've got a spreadsheet for budgeting that has columns for estimated costs (E) and actualized costs (F). As I start to add actualized numbers to the column (F), I'd like to see how much the total cost is compared to the estimated total cost.

Is there a formula I can add that will look at the whole actualized column (F) and if a cell row is empty, look at the cell in column E of the same row and add them all up?

Comment: Without an example try something like `=SUM(IF(F:F="",E:E,F:F))`

Comment: @JvdV just tried testing this formula and it's providing weird results. It seems to be sourcing from E. If I tried adding cells to the F column, it SOMETIMES switches to sourcing from F. Any ideas?